# Can ReSharper run unit tests automatically

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is it possible to automatically run unit tests while you work without compiling or running them manually? I am aware that [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) allows you to do so, but I would prefer to use the ReSharper suite.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has been available since dotCover 10. See [the dotCover documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Work_with_Continuous_Testing.html) for details.

This adds a new panel "Continuous Testing Session" as well as a new status icon in the gutter.

Note that Visual Studio also has this feature, known as [Live Unit Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/live-unit-testing?view=vs-2019).

---

[image]

Comment: PS. Also a Com Truise fan :)

Comment: +1 for the updates on the Resharper plugin. I'm glad there finally adding this. Also glad you're a fan too!

Answer (score 5):

Not possible with Resharper at the moment, you will need something like [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) that runs your unit tests continuously in the background, highlighting code that breaks them as you write it and fails your tests.

Edit: At the time of my response it wasn't possible to do this with ReSharper but now in Version 10 it is, see Drew Noakes's answer. You could still give NCrunch a try as it continuously runs your tests in the background even without doing an explicit save.

Comment: Wow...I hope that jetbrains one day include it as a feature. It would be so useful. Also thanks for your help!

Comment: 2018: (with only resharper & 2015) - is there still no solution ?